# How to set the text style property of a field content in LiveCode

Tags: text, properties, field, livecode

I have a scrolling field in my LiveCode app that looks like this:

> A: John Rogers 234 9th
>    B: Henry Ford 555 1st
>    C: Jane Fonda 224 5th

I want to make the last words (the positions i.e 9th, 1st, 5th) in each line have a specific text styling. For example, make it red in color.

I tried several things including iterating over the lines with this code:

```
repeat for each line lC in  field "fcontent"  
  set the foregroundColor of lC to "red"  
end repeat
```

...but kept getting an error. Please someone put me on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution using the foreGroundColor is almost right. You need to use the textColor instead and you can't use the repeat for each control structure in this case.

```
repeat with x = 1 to the number of lines of fld "fcontent"
  set the textColor of the last word of line x of fld "fcontent" to red
end repeat
```

Red doesn't need quotes, because it is defines as a constant in LiveCode.

Comment: But why 'repeat for each' structure does not work here?

Comment: Your LC variable in your repeat-foreach loop is a string, not a chunk references. Chunk references are of the form "line x to y of field z of card c" while strings are really just strings ("9th", "1st" and "5th"). Therefore, you can set the textColor of a chunk reference but not of a string.

Comment: I just noticed... it isn't yours but dtechplus's.

Answer (score 2):

Marks solution is the right one. Looking at your question, you mentioned wanting to set the colour of the last word of each line. You can add "the last word of" to Mark's script and you should get exactly what you're looking for:

```
repeat with x = 1 to the number of lines of fld "fcontent"
   set the textColor of the last word of line x of fld "fcontent" to "255,0,100"
end repeat
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks man. I somehow omitted 'last word' when posting my code. But I now know my main mistake is not realizing I had to use textColor and not foregroundColor!